# SQL Server iSCSI session issue with a NetApp SAN

Tags: sql-server, iscsi, netapp

We had an issue early this morning when iSCSI issues broke connectivity with a few of our databases (resulting in a SQL Server Error 21). Attempts to `DBCC CheckDB` did not work, and the only solution was to restart the SQL Service.

Is there a known reason why an iSCSI initiator session would reset itself out of the blue?

Example below from the NetApp syslog. This set of errors was replicated 4 times (once for each SQL server in production). Only one SQL server was noticeably impacted, however.

```
[san1: iscsi.notice:notice]: ISCSI: iswta, ISID Rule: new connection from same initiator, shutting down old session 7
[san1: iscsi.notice:notice]: ISCSI: iswta, New session from initiator iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:sql1.example.corp at IP addr 10.xxx.xxx.123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just shows the initiator reconnecting.  You probably need to look at the Windows event log to see why the client initiator needed to reconnect.

Also, you'll probably get better feedback on the [NetApp Community](http://communities.netapp.com).